# event onclick add table, but if already exits remove when click again

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a few inputs and an onclick button that save the value of the inputs in a table when the button is click, but if it is clicked again it creates another table below the older one. I would like to remove the older table every time I create a new one.

This is the html

```
<p id="todaInfo"></p>
  <div class="container" id="preguntas">        
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>Ingresa tus datos para iniciar una cotizacion</h3>
      <table class="table table-striped">    
      <thead>
          <input type="text" id="nombre" class="no-outline" placeholder="Nombre">
          <input type="number" id="edad" class="no-outline" placeholder="Edad">
          <input type="email" id="email" class="no-outline" placeholder="Email">
          <input type="tel" id="telefono" class="no-outline" placeholder="Telefono">
          <div>
            <button onclick="Guardar()" id="guardado">Guardar</button>
          </div>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="info" class="shadow">          
      </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
```

This is the javascript

```
function Guardar() {
    datosJSON.nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    datosJSON.edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
    datosJSON.email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    datosJSON.telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
    localStorage.setItem('datosSolictante', JSON.stringify(datosJSON));
} // Cierre funcion guardar


function checkData() {
    console.log(todaInfo);
    console.log(((nombre.value) && (edad.value) && (email.value) && (telefono.value)));
    if ((nombre.value) && (edad.value) && (email.value) && (telefono.value)) {
    console.log(todaInfo);
    todaInfo.innerHTML = ` ${nombre.value} ${edad.value} ${email.value} ${telefono.value}  `;
}} // Cierre funcion checkData

window.onload = function() {
    let todaInfo = document.getElementById('todaInfo');
    let info = document.getElementById('info');
    console.log(todaInfo);
    console.log(info);
    todaInfo.innerHTML = '';
    var guardado = document.getElementById('guardado');
    guardado.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (checkData) {
        guardado.innerHTML = `Guardado`;
    }
});
};

guardado.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if ((nombre.value.length > 0) && (edad.value.length > 0) && (email.value.length > 0) && (telefono.value.length > 0)) {
        info.innerHTML += "<th>Informacion del cliente</th><tr><td>Nombre: " + nombre.value + "</tr></td><tr><td>Edad: " + edad.value + "</tr></td><tr><td>Email: " + email.value + "</tr></td><tr><td>Telefono: " + telefono.value + "</td></tr>"; 
    }
    nombre.value = "";
    edad.value = "";
    email.value = "";
    telefono.value = "";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the `info.innerHTML`. Currently you are adding to `innerHTML` every time you click the button.

```
if ((nombre.value.length > 0) && (edad.value.length > 0) && (email.value.length > 0) && (telefono.value.length > 0)) {
    info.innerHTML = "<th>Informacion del cliente</th><tr><td>Nombre: " + nombre.value + "</tr></td><tr><td>Edad: " + edad.value + "</tr></td><tr><td>Email: " + email.value + "</tr></td><tr><td>Telefono: " + telefono.value + "</td></tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anish, but how do you do that?

Comment: Currently you are doing `info.innerHTML += "..."`.
You can do as I have written in the answer without the `+`.

Comment: I didn't see that difference with my code before. It works pefect! thank you!